# Is it true that for every regular language $L \subseteq \{0, 1\}^{*}$ the language $\{w^{|w|} |w \in L \}$ is also regular?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, regular-language, pumping-lemma

Is it true that for every regular language $L \subseteq \{0, 1\}^{*}$ the language $\{w^{|w|} |w \in L \}$ is also regular?

I think the language is not regular because for a finite w we can easily construct DFA by chaining |w| DFAs that accept w but |w| is not bounded therefore we need a non-finite automaton !

Comment: By $w^{|w|}$, do you mean the string $w$ catenated with itself $|w|$ times?

Comment: @MarkSaving correct.

Comment: Your intuitions are correct, but you need to do more to prove the language is not regular. The standard tool for this is the [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) and it should work here.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, it is not even true that for every regular language $L \subseteq \{1\}^*$, the language $L' = \{w^{|w|} \mid w \in L\}$ is regular.

In particular, let $S_V = \{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid 1^n \in V\}$ for all languages $V \subseteq \{1\}^*$. Note that $V = \{1^n \mid n \in S_V\} = \{s \in \{1\}^* \mid |s| \in S_v\}$.

Clearly, we see that $S_{L'} = \{n^2 \mid n \in S_L\}$ for all $L \subseteq \{1\}^*$.

Now take $L = \{1\}^*$. Then we see that $S_{L'} = \{n^2 \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. That is, $L'$ is the set of all strings whose length is a perfect square.

I will leave it as an exercise to apply the pumping lemma and finish the proof.

Comment: Thank you again.